# How do I add a letter to a string constantly till recursion ends without using any imports?

Tags: python, recursion

> Hi I was thinking how do I add a letter into a string at any position.

For example, I want to add up all 'abc' so I recursion it and it starts from ''.

then `[''] ->['c'] ->['bc','cb'] ->['abc','bac','bca','acb','cab','cba']`

How do I make the `'b'` add to the first position of the string and last position of the `'c'`?

So far I have been just keep testing and I got this and I do not know how to proceed further.

```
def permutation(x):
    if x == '':
        return ['']

    a=x[0]
    b=permutation(x[1:])
    c=[]
    for i in b:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            d= list(i)
            d.append(a)
permutation('abc')
```

Comment: This is a horrid problem for recursion, is there any particular reason why you'd want recursion specifically? There is absolutely no reason why this problem should be solved using recursion

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I don't think this problem is _horrid_ for recursion,  but the example is really strange.

Comment: @funnydman The recursion approach here super inefficient, recursion should only really be used for problems that make sense to "divide and conquer".  This is a simple case for iteration, divide and conquer actively hinders the ability to get to the correct solution here. (especially if you avoid iteration completely, note how it would require figuring out how to fit a character in a particular slot without the loop)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh don't restrict to the best solution, if the OP want to do problem with recursion then help them on that way, you can also add the other solution as well, if you think it is not achiveable by recursion then say so, , just don't restrict the thought